# How to dynamically fill different paths of an SVG?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, svg-animate

I have this kind of working

```
<svg>
  <path>
  <path>
  <path>
  // lots more paths in here
</svg>

useLayoutEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
        setCount((count) => count + 1)
        addAnimation()
    }, 2000)
    return () => {
        clearInterval(interval)
    }
}, [count])

const addAnimation = () => {
    if (count < 200) {
        const svg = document.querySelector('svg')
        let anim = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'animate')
        anim.setAttribute('begin', '0s')
        anim.setAttribute('from', '#F2F4F9')
        anim.setAttribute('to', '#ACE1DE')
        anim.setAttribute('fill', 'freeze')
        anim.setAttribute('dur', '1.5s')
        anim.setAttribute('repeatCount', 1)
        anim.setAttribute('attributeName', 'fill')


        svg.children[count].appendChild(anim)
    }
}
```

so what im doing is every 2 seconds, im calling my function and passing in the new count
it's doing it for the first one but every subsequent one isn't being filled

what's weird is if I log out: `svg.children[count].appendChild(anim)` and inspect the DOM it shows the appended thing. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: After 1.5 seconds the animation is over. So adding it again will do nothing as the animation timeline has passed that point.

Comment: @RobertLongson how do you mean? when I call the function again it should begin that process again

Comment: sorry I've replaced `55` to now use `count`. if that was confusing you

Comment: Imagine time passing from 0s to 1s to 2s. That's the animation timeline. You create some animations at 0s to begin at 0s, they run. You create the same animations when the timeline is at 2s or 3s etc and they won't run because they are in the past.

Comment: @RobertLongson what is the `0s` referring to here? I assumed  the moment it was created. how can I solve this ?

Comment: You have a 0s in the begin attribute, that's when your animation begins. As for the timeline, time passes as you view the page. Imagine you have a stopwatch and a rule that says shout bang at 0s on the stopwatch. You start the stopwatch, how many times do you shout bang? **Once.** After that it's too late, if someone comes to you with a note that says "shout bang at 0s", you can ignore it because 0s has already passed.

Comment: so the 0 is nothing in relation to the calling of the function? I just want to say "call it at beginning of initialising"

Comment: I still dont get that. coz the element gets created at the calling of each function, so how has it passed that time?

Comment: @RobertLongson ok figured it out! I need to call begin: "indefinite", and then: ` anim.beginElement()`

Comment: that would certainly work as would querying the current point in the timeline and using that [SVGSVGElement.getCurrentTime()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGSVGElement)